# Bitcoin transaction 0/3 confirmation. How do i check on this?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, blockexplorer

Bitcoin transaction received Nov. 10 and is still 0/3 confirmation.  How do i check on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the details of the transaction, you can search for it (using the transaction id or sending or receiving address) on a block explorer website such as [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/).

Once you have an understanding of the fee paid, in satoshi's per byte, you can see where that fits in the backlog of transactions, using a site that analyses unconfirmed transactions and their fees, like [Johoe's Mempool Statistics](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#24h)

Further details on what to do are available on the [canonical question about unconfirmed transactions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/516).